# qml mapToItem for quickmap item

Tags: qt, qml

I have a qml map, and a qml quick map item, wen I click on a point on map it places quick map item, well my quick map item is an image which is 300px in 300px, I want to get the coordinate of point(200,200) of image on map, I know that there is a function which is named `item.mapToItem(item,x,y)`, Well I tried to use this function but it returns wrong values,Here is my whole code

```
 Map {
                  id:map
                  anchors.fill: parent
                  plugin: mapPlugin
                  center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75) // Oslo
                  zoomLevel: 7
                  MapQuickItem{
                      id:imagQuickitem
                      zoomLevel:1
                      sourceItem:Image {
                          id:image
                          asynchronous:true
                          smooth: false
                          transformOrigin: Item.Center
                          antialiasing: false


                          //visible: false

                           MouseArea{
                               anchors.fill: parent ;
                               onPressed:
                               {
                                   if(!gcplistener && currentTool=="addgcp"){
                                       gcpimgposition=Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y);
                                       console.log("The first point is set")
                                       currentgcppoint.row=gcpimgposition.x;
                                       currentgcppoint.column=gcpimgposition.y;
                                       gcplistener=true;
                                   }

                                   console.log(mouse.x + " "+ mouse.y)
                                   console.log( imagQuickitem.mapToItem(map,mouse.x,mouse.y).x+ " "+imagQuickitem.mapToItem(map,mouse.x,mouse.y).y)

                                    console.log( imagQuickitem.mapFromItem(map,mouse.x,mouse.y).x+ " "+imagQuickitem.mapFromItem(map,mouse.x,mouse.y).y)
                               }
                           }





                      }
                      coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75)
                  }
                  Row {
                      id: containerRow
                      layoutDirection: rightEdge() ? Qt.LeftToRight : Qt.RightToLeft
                      anchors.top: parent.top
                      anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                      anchors.right: rightEdge() ? parent.right : undefined
                      anchors.left: rightEdge() ? undefined : parent.left

                      Button {
                          id: sliderToggler
                          width: 32
                          height: 96
                          checkable: true
                          checked: true
                          anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

                          transform:  Scale {
                                          origin.x: rightEdge() ? 0 : sliderToggler.width / 2
                                          xScale: rightEdge() ? 1 : -1
                                      }

                          style:  ButtonStyle {
                                      background: Rectangle {
                                          color: "transparent"
                                      }
                                  }

                          property real shear: 0.333
                          property real buttonOpacity: 0.5
                          property real mirror : rightEdge() ? 1.0 : -1.0

                          Rectangle {
                              width: 16
                              height: 48
                              color: "seagreen"
                              antialiasing: true
                              opacity: sliderToggler.buttonOpacity
                              anchors.top: parent.top
                              anchors.left: sliderToggler.checked ?  parent.left : parent.horizontalCenter
                              transform: Matrix4x4 {
                                  property real d : sliderToggler.checked ? 1.0 : -1.0
                                  matrix:    Qt.matrix4x4(1.0,  d * sliderToggler.shear,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                          0.0,    1.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                          0.0,    0.0,    1.0,    0.0,
                                                          0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.0)
                              }
                          }

                          Rectangle {
                              width: 16
                              height: 48
                              color: "seagreen"
                              antialiasing: true
                              opacity: sliderToggler.buttonOpacity
                              anchors.top: parent.verticalCenter
                              anchors.right: sliderToggler.checked ?  parent.right : parent.horizontalCenter
                              transform: Matrix4x4 {
                                  property real d : sliderToggler.checked ? -1.0 : 1.0
                                  matrix:    Qt.matrix4x4(1.0,  d * sliderToggler.shear,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                          0.0,    1.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                          0.0,    0.0,    1.0,    0.0,
                                                          0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.0)
                              }
                          }
                      }

                      Rectangle {
                          id: sliderContainer
                          height: parent.height
                          width: sliderRow.width + 10
                          visible: sliderToggler.checked
                          color: Qt.rgba( 0, 191 / 255.0, 255 / 255.0, 0.07)

                          property var labelBorderColor: "transparent"
                          property var slidersHeight : sliderContainer.height
                                                       - rowSliderValues.height
                                                       - rowSliderLabels.height
                                                       - sliderColumn.spacing * 2
                                                       - sliderColumn.topPadding
                                                       - sliderColumn.bottomPadding
                          MouseArea{
                              onPressed: {
                                  console.log("test")
                              }
                          }

                          Column {
                              id: sliderColumn
                              spacing: 10
                              topPadding: 16
                              bottomPadding: 48
                              anchors.centerIn: parent




                              // the sliders value labels
                              Row {
                                  id: rowSliderValues
                                  spacing: sliderRow.spacing
                                  width: sliderRow.width
                                  height: 32
                                  property real entryWidth: zoomSlider.width

                                  Rectangle{
                                      color: labelBackground
                                      height: parent.height
                                      width: parent.entryWidth
                                      border.color: sliderContainer.labelBorderColor
                                      Label {
                                          id: labelZoomValue
                                          text: zoomSlider.value.toFixed(3)
                                          font.pixelSize: fontSize
                                          rotation: -90
                                          anchors.centerIn: parent
                                      }
                                  }
                                  Rectangle{
                                      color: labelBackground
                                      height: parent.height
                                      width: parent.entryWidth
                                      border.color: sliderContainer.labelBorderColor
                                      Label {
                                          id: labelBearingValue
                                          text: opacityslider.value.toFixed(2)
                                          font.pixelSize: fontSize
                                          rotation: -90
                                          anchors.centerIn: parent
                                      }
                                  }
                                  Rectangle{
                                      color: labelBackground
                                      height: parent.height
                                      width: parent.entryWidth
                                      border.color: sliderContainer.labelBorderColor
                                      Label {
                                          id: labelTiltValue
                                          text: imagescale.value.toFixed(2)
                                          font.pixelSize: fontSize
                                          rotation: -90
                                          anchors.centerIn: parent
                                      }
                                  }
                                  Rectangle{
                                      color: labelBackground
                                      height: parent.height
                                      width: parent.entryWidth
                                      border.color: sliderContainer.labelBorderColor
                                      Label {
                                          id: labelFovValue
                                          text: rotationslider.value.toFixed(2)
                                          font.pixelSize: fontSize
                                          rotation: -90
                                          anchors.centerIn: parent
                                      }
                                  }
                              } // rowSliderValues

                              // The sliders row
                              Row {
                                  spacing: -10
                                  id: sliderRow
                                  height: sliderContainer.slidersHeight

                                  C2.Slider {
                                      id: zoomSlider
                                      height: parent.height
                                      orientation : Qt.Vertical
                                      from : map.minimumZoomLevel
                                      to : map.maximumZoomLevel
                                      value : map.zoomLevel
                                      onValueChanged: {
                                              map.zoomLevel = value
                                      }
                                  }
                                  C2.Slider {
                                      id: opacityslider
                                      height: parent.height
                                      from: 0
                                      to: 1
                                      orientation : Qt.Vertical
                                      value: image.opacity
                                      onValueChanged: {
                                          image.opacity = value;
                                      }
                                  }
                                  C2.Slider {
                                      id: imagescale
                                      height: parent.height
                                      orientation : Qt.Vertical
                                      from: 0;
                                      to: 5
                                      value: image.scale
                                      onValueChanged: {
                                          image.scale= value;
                                          rectangular.scale=value;
                                      }
                                  }
                                  C2.Slider {
                                      id: rotationslider
                                      height: parent.height
                                      orientation : Qt.Vertical
                                      from: 0
                                      to: 360
                                      value: image.rotation
                                      onValueChanged: {
                                          image.rotation = value;
                                          rectangular.rotation=value
                                      }
                                  }
                              } // Row sliders

                              // The labels row
                              Row {
                                  id: rowSliderLabels
                                  spacing: sliderRow.spacing
                                  width: sliderRow.width
                                  property real entryWidth: zoomSlider.width
                                  property real entryHeight: 64

                                  Rectangle{
                                      color: labelBackground
                                      height: parent.entryHeight
                                      width: parent.entryWidth
                                      border.color: sliderContainer.labelBorderColor
                                      Label {
                                          id: labelZoom
                                          text: "Map Zoom"
                                          font.pixelSize: fontSize
                                          rotation: -90
                                          anchors.centerIn: parent
                                      }
                                  }

                                  Rectangle{
                                      color: labelBackground
                                      height: parent.entryHeight
                                      width: parent.entryWidth
                                      border.color: sliderContainer.labelBorderColor
                                      Label {
                                          id: labelBearing
                                          text: "Image Opacity"
                                          font.pixelSize: fontSize
                                          rotation: -90
                                          anchors.centerIn: parent
                                      }
                                  }
                                  Rectangle{
                                      color: labelBackground
                                      height: parent.entryHeight
                                      width: parent.entryWidth
                                      border.color: sliderContainer.labelBorderColor
                                      Label {
                                          id: labelTilt
                                          text: "Image Scale"
                                          font.pixelSize: fontSize
                                          rotation: -90
                                          anchors.centerIn: parent
                                      }
                                  }
                                  Rectangle{
                                      color: labelBackground
                                      height: parent.entryHeight
                                      width: parent.entryWidth
                                      border.color: sliderContainer.labelBorderColor
                                      Label {
                                          id: labelFov
                                          text: "Image Rotation"
                                          font.pixelSize: fontSize
                                          rotation: -90
                                          anchors.centerIn: parent
                                      }
                                  }
                              } // rowSliderLabels
                          } // Column
                      } // sliderContainer
                  }







                  MouseArea {
                      anchors.fill: parent
                      propagateComposedEvents: true

                            onClicked: mouse.accepted = false;
                            onReleased: mouse.accepted = false;
                            onDoubleClicked: mouse.accepted = false;
                            onPositionChanged: mouse.accepted = false;
                            onPressAndHold: mouse.accepted = false;
                            onPressed: {
                                  mouse.accepted = false;
                                  if(imagesourcepoint==null){
                                      imagesourcepoint=Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y)
                                      imagQuickitem.coordinate= map.toCoordinate(imagesourcepoint)
                                      rectangular.topLeft=map.toCoordinate(imagesourcepoint);
                                      var w=((image.width*0.0016)+map.toCoordinate(imagesourcepoint).longitude);
                                      var h=(map.toCoordinate(imagesourcepoint).latitude)+(image.height*1.5);
                                      console.log(w)
                                      console.log(h)
                                      if(!image.visible){
                                          image.visible=true
                                      }

                                  }




                          switch(currentTool){

                          case "addgcp":
                              gcppoint=map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y));
                              if(gcplistener){

                                  row.text=gcpimgposition.x;
                                  col.text=gcpimgposition.y;
                                  x.text=gcppoint.longitude;
                                  y.text=gcppoint.latitude;
                                  inputgcpDialog.open();




                              }else{
                                      currentgcppoint.lat=gcppoint.latitude;
                                      currentgcppoint.lon=gcppoint.longitude;
                              }

                              if(gcpimgposition==null&&gcplistener==false){
                                  //user must click on image
                                  //FIXME:
                                   messages.displayMessage("Please click on image, not outside");
                              }
                                gcpimgposition==null;

                              break;
                          case "moveimage":
                              //moving image
                              if(moveimageEnabled){
                                  imagQuickitem.coordinate= map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y))
                              }

                              break;
                          }

                              console.log(map.width + " "+ map.height)
                              console.log("z: "+map.zoomLevel )

                              console.log("image.mapToItem: "+ image.mapToItem(map,0,0).x+ " "+image.mapToItem(map,0,0).y)
                              console.log("image coordinate on map: "+ image.mapToItem(map,image.width,image.height).x+ " "+image.mapToItem(map,image.width,image.height).y)

//                              console.log( map.mapFromItem(null,0,0).x+ " "+map.mapFromItem(null,0,0).y)

//                              console.log( map.mapToItem(imagQuickitem,0,0).x+ " "+map.mapToItem(imagQuickitem,0,0).y)

//                               console.log( map.mapFromItem(imagQuickitem,0,0).x+ " "+map.mapFromItem(imagQuickitem,0,0).y)
                              onPressed: console.log('latitude = '+ (map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y)).latitude),
                                                                 'longitude = '+ (map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y)).longitude));
                          }
                      }
                  }
```

well, my problem is in part Maps Mouse Area which I expect to get the coordinate of clicked point on Map object based o quickmapitems coordinate using mapToItem  function.
My main function is in Mouse pressed button,In above code I expect `image.mapToItem(map,0,0).y)` to return the same as        `console.log(mouse.x + " "+ mouse.y)` as the `mouse.x` and `mouse.y` are the position of (0,0) of image which are mapped on Map items coordinate, I know how to converts maps coordinate to geographic coordinate 
I also kept some codes of sliders in map control as I think there must be a relation between these parameters and main map controls mapToItem function

Comment: I recommend you place the necessary code, the comments are good if they give options or clarifications, but they will only make your code unclear.

Comment: Please pare your code down to just the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem. Remove the `ColumnLayout`, the `GroupBox`, the `RowLayout`. Remove sliders. Remove commented out code. Make a game out of seeing how few characters you can use to reproduce the problem. Then edit your question with that code, and include (a) what you do (e.g. click on...), (b) what you EXPECTED to happen, and (c) what happened instead. Your current code and question are unlikely to get you help because it is too much irrelevant code, and not clear what your problem is.

Comment: Do you know that you can use [`anchorPoint`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapquickitem.html#anchorPoint-prop) on a `MapQuickItem` to choose what will be at a location? Also, it sounds like you might want [`toCoordinate()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html#toCoordinate-method) which converts a mouse location to a coordinate on the map.

Comment: @eyllanesc hi, thanks I have removed the unnecessary parts, the map object is now available,

Comment: @Phrogz thanks for your comment, now I have edited my question

Comment: @MajidHojati But you did not really follow my advice.

Comment: @Phrogz Hi, Yes I tied to clean up my question,I also kept some codes of sliders in map control as I think there must be a relation between these parameters and main map control

Answer (score 1):

You must call `mapToItem()` to replace image of `imagQuickitem`.
Use below code in `MouseArea`

```
var coor = image.mapToItem(map , 0 ,0)
```

Thanks